# @Async with for loop in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, for-loop, asynchronous

I have following scenario.

- there is some kind of daily calculation, which can be done retroactively for  months.
- it's very time consuming, involves lots of calculations
- no day is dependent on the result of any other day, every day is standalone.
- calculations will be triggered from web API
- all the results will be saved for later use
- all methods are void

So, I was thinking about for loop that would calculate multiple days at time, since there is no need to know about results of other days, but i cant figure how to do this properly.

where do I put the `@Async` annotation?

method for JAX is as follows:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/calculated")
public void calculated(String req,
                         final @Context SecurityContext securityContext,
                         final @Suspended AsyncResponse response2) {

    logger.info("calculating");
    ThymeDate thymeDate =  parseJSONDate(req);

    thymeNewDateRange.getDataForDateRange(thymeDate, null);

}
```

this will send object that has date a and date b into `getDataForDateRange` method, which will then loop days between a and b.

```
 public void iterateOverDays(ThymeDate thymeDate) {
        for (LocalDate date : new DateRange(thymeDate.getDate_a(), thymeDate.getDate_b())) {
             ControlService.dailyCalculation(date, null);
        }
```

and as stated before, `dailyCalculation` method is huge so i will not paste the code for it, but it is a void method with many calculations in it.

I've tried to put `@Async` into `dailyCalculation` method, but application started to skip days and do multiple calculation on some days, seemingly randomly.

I also tried to put it in JAX and for loop method, which lead to async not being used at all.

i have following Executor in my AppConfig:

```
@Bean
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("calc-thread-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: Is the `dailyCalculation` and `getDataForDateRange` in the same class? The class that has the `@Async` on it, is it a spring component? Have you enabled async on the `@SpringBootApplication` or `@Configuration` class?

Comment: they are not in the same class. it think @Service is same as component? and yes i have enabled it, and it is a configuration class. if i put async annotation on dailyCalculation it will start up more than 1 thread but starts skipping days :(

Comment: Can you show the `getDataForDateRange` method or even better the `thymeNewDateRange` class? Are you auto wiring `ControlService` into `thymeNewDateRange`?

Comment: Did you put EnableAsync in your spring boot Application.java? I would go with your initial instinct and put the Async annotations right above the signature of dailyCalculation. It should work just fine, and you can check to see which arguments the method is taking with each iteration.